# Directories within File List in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I am documenting my project right now!
So as it stands, under "File List", I see something like this:

```
File List
Folder1/Sub_Folder1/File01
Folder1/Sub_Folder1/File02
Folder2/Sub_Folder1/File01
```

And what I'd like to see instead is this:

```
File List
Folder1
Folder2
```

Upon expending Folder1, it should look like this:

```
File List
Folder1
       \Sub_Folder1
Folder2
```

Is this possible in Doxygen?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! In the doxygen configuration file..

SHOW_DIRECTORIES = YES

Will do the trick ;)